# A way to declare a constant value in a type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to declare a typeclass that has some implemented functions which utilize an unimplemented constant value (`table`):

```
class FromRow a => StdQueries a where
  table :: String
  byId :: Int -> QueryM (Maybe a)
  byId = fmap listToMaybe . queryM sql . Only
    where sql = read $ "SELECT * FROM " ++ table ++ " WHERE id = ?"
```

The idea is simple: I want to get the `byId` (and other similar functions) available by instantiating this typeclass by specifying just the `table`:

```
instance StdQueries SomeType where
  table = "the_constant_value_for_this_type"
```

But the compiler keeps complaining with the following message:

```
The class method `table'
mentions none of the type variables of the class StdQueries a
When checking the class method: table :: String
In the class declaration for `StdQueries'
```

Are there any solutions to that kind of a problem? Can tricking with `newtype` help or anything like that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is

```
class FromRow a => StdQueries a where
    byId :: Int -> QueryM (Maybe a)

defaultById :: FromRow a => String -> Int -> QueryM (Maybe a)
defaultById table = fmap listToMaybe . queryM sql . Only
    where sql = read $ "SELECT * FROM " ++ table ++ " WHERE id = ?"

instance StdQueries SomeType where
    byId = defaultById "the_constant_value_for_this_type"
```

This is simple, but if you have more than one function that needs access to the `table` value, you have to specify that value more than once.

You can avoid that, and sabauma's need for `undefined` and `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` like this:

```
newtype Table a = Table String

class FromRow a => StdQueries a where
    table :: Table a
    byId :: Int -> QueryM (Maybe a)
    byId = defaultById table

defaultById :: StdQueries a => Table a -> Int -> QueryM (Maybe a)
defaultById (Table table) = fmap listToMaybe . queryM sql . Only
    where sql = read $ "SELECT * FROM " ++ table ++ " WHERE id = ?"

instance StdQueries SomeType where
    table = Table "the_constant_value_for_this_type"
```

The magic here is the type signature for `defaultById`, which forces `byId` to provide the `table` from the same instance. If we provided `defaultById :: (StdQueries a, StdQueries b) => Table a -> Int -> QueryM (Maybe b)` then `defaultById` would still compile, but we would still get a similar error message to the one in your question: the compiler would no longer know which definition of `table` to use.

By making `Table a` a `data` structure instead of a `newtype` wrapper, you can extend this to specify many fields in the constant, if required.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the definition of `table` does not mention any of the type variables of the class, so there would not be any way to figure out which version of `table` to use. A (admittedly hackish) solution might be something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
class FromRow a => StdQueries a where
  table :: a -> String
  byId :: Int -> QueryM (Maybe a)
  byId = fmap listToMaybe . queryM sql . Only
    where sql = read $ "SELECT * FROM " ++ table (undefined :: a) ++ " WHERE id = ?"

instance StdQueries SomeType where
    table = const "the_constant_value_for_this_type"
```

Which you could then use via

```
table (undefined :: SomeType) == "the_constant_value_for_this_type"
```

Not that I would really recommend doing this.

Comment: There's not much wrong with this, lots of type classes do it this way.

Comment: please format your code to make it more readable; also, does this really work? it looks like you are making `table` a function now, but you're not using it that way in the `where sql = ...` part.

Comment: type of table is `a -> String` and not `String` so how are you concatenating it ?

Comment: you should do `table (undefined :: a)` and use extension `ScopedTypeVariables`

Comment: @Satvik Forgot to fix the use of `table` in the class definition. It should be usable now.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was not aware of that. I just get uncomfortable when I see `undefined` floating around.

Comment: @sabauma: If you really want to, you can go via `data Proxy a = Proxy`, which gives you `table :: Proxy a -> String` and `table (Proxy :: Proxy SomeType)`. A bit more verbose, but much safer.

Comment: `Storable`'s `sizeOf` function is probably the most common example of passing an argument to identify the type.  The `crypto-api` uses the `Proxy` solution (via the `tagged` library) to solve this problem.