# Haskell type `forall a . (Num a, Integral a) => a` for an integer constant of many types

Tags: haskell

When writing FFI code in haskell, I often have `Int` and `CInt` variables mixed together. I tried to define a new type `Intlike` to help with defining constants that can be represented as values of either type, as follows:

```
type Intlike = forall a . (Num a, Integral a) => a
floatSize :: Intlike = fromIntegral $ sizeOf (1 :: CFloat)
```

Then GHCi complains so:

```
Fractal.hs:276:24-35: No instance for (Num Intlike) arising from \
                                         a use of ‘fromIntegral’ …
    In the expression: fromIntegral
    In the expression: fromIntegral $ sizeOf (1 :: CFloat)
    In a pattern binding:
      floatSize :: Intlike = fromIntegral $ sizeOf (1 :: CFloat)
Compilation failed.
```

(This is with the `Rank2Types` language extension.)

The following, however, works:

```
floatSize :: (Num a, Integral a) => a
floatSize = fromIntegral $ sizeOf (1 :: CFloat)
```

Is there a good solution that doesn't have me write `fromIntegral` all the time? What is the difference between `Intlike` and the one that works? They look similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you *why*, but if you write

```
floatSize :: Intlike
floatSize = fromIntegral $ sizeOf (1 :: CFloat)
```

then it works just fine. One possibility is that the type annotation on the pattern variable is doing something other than what you expected (I've never really understood what those do). Note that your `Num` context is redundant, because `Integral` is a subclass of `Num`. As for `fromIntegral`, you will need that just about any time you need to switch between integral types. Another option is to use "generic" functions that give you what you need. For example, you could define

```
import Foreign.Storable (sizeOf, Storable)

genericSizeOf :: (Storable a, Integral b) => a -> b
genericSizeOf = fromIntegral . sizeOf
```

Side note: when using functions like `sizeOf` that take an argument solely for its type, I personally prefer to use `undefined` rather than an arbitrary value. So I'd write something like `sizeOf (undefined::CInt)` rather than `sizeof (1::CInt)`. This makes it clear that it doesn't matter what value I'm passing in, and reduces the mental clutter of "What is this 1? What would happen if I changed it to 2?"

---

In the comments below, Boyd Stephen Smith, Jr., mentions another approach that is apparently to be preferred, although I have not yet read up on it.

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that. Expanding the type explicitly also works: `floatSize :: (forall ...) = ...`.

Comment: Regarding `fromIntegral`: I get one for every `CInt` (or `CSize`) by `Int` multiplication, it's not that few.

Comment: @Kirill, I expanded my answer to show how to cut down on `fromIntegral`s.

Comment: For functions that take are argument just for it's type, they should use the type signature `p a -> b` and be called either with the value `Proxy :: Proxy a` (if being pedantic) or `[] :: [a]` (if being obscure).

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr., what does a type signature `p a -> b` even mean?

Comment: I'd not sure specifically what you are asking, but it allows a dependency on the type chosen for `a`, but not a dependency on a particular value of `a`, since (in general) there's no way to extract an value of type `a` from a value of type `p a`.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. So using `p a` is a promise not to evaluate the argument? (As opposed to using `undefined`, which doesn't promise but fails at runtime instead?) TBH, this seems a bit over-kill for something as simple as `sizeOf`.

Comment: @Kirill http://stackoverflow.com/a/22116440/2008899 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13629758/2008899 (in the comments) plus http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.2/docs/Data-Tagged.html which mentions not only is it safer, but it optimizes better.