# Using Proxy in a TypeClass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629538/a-way-to-declare-a-constant-value-in-a-type-class).

I'd like to define a typeclass

```
class Wrapper f where
    wrap :: a -> f a
    unwrap :: f a -> a
    name :: Proxy (f a) -> String
```

and then define

```
instance (IsString a, FromJSON a, Wrapper f) => FromJSON (f a) where
    parseJSON (String s) = wrap <$> pure (fromString $ unpack s)
    parseJSON invalid    = typeMismatch (name (Proxy :: Proxy (f a))) invalid
```

But I'm getting an error saying that

```
Could not deduce (Wrapper f0) arising from a use of ‘name’                                               
      from the context: (IsString a, FromJSON a, Wrapper f)                                                    
        bound by the instance declaration at src/Model/Wrapper.hs:29:10-62                                     
      The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous
```

It's not really clear to me why this doesn't work and if it possible to fix it somehow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First a couple of remarks:

1. *Don't define such an instance*. This instance would match *anything* of the form `f a`, regardless of whether `f` is actually in the `Wrapper` class. In particular, it would also conflict with standard instances such as `FromJSON (Vector a)`, even though `Vector` *can't* be a (well-behaved) instance of `Wrapper`. The reason for this is that Haskell's typeclass system is based on an *open-world assumption*: the compiler can never assume that a type is not in some class, because anybody could, at least technically speaking, add the instance later.
2. I would advice against using `Proxy` in new code. I always considered `Proxy` an ugly hack, barely less ugly than the `undefined :: T` arguments that were commonly used for this in old Haskell code. In new GHC, the problem was fixed properly by [`-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-AllowAmbiguousTypes) with [`-XTypeApplications`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications); these allow you to simply make the signature

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
   class Wrapper f where
     ...
     name :: String
   ```

   and then instead of `name (Proxy :: Proxy (f a))` write only `name @f`.

Now to the actual problem: your code doesn't work because type variables in standard Haskell always only belong to a single type signature / class context, but aren't usable in the code that defines it. IOW, type variables don't use the same *name scopes* as value-variables, that's why when you mention `Proxy (f a)` the compiler “disambiguates” the type variables to `f0` and `a0`. This is a bit of a silly shortcoming of Haskell98, and is adressed by the [`-XScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ScopedTypeVariables) extension (together with the `∀` aka `forall` keyword). The following would compile, by itself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}
instance ∀ f a .  (IsString a, FromJSON a, Wrapper f) => FromJSON (f a) where
    parseJSON (String s) = wrap <$> pure (fromString $ unpack s)
    parseJSON invalid    = typeMismatch (name (Proxy :: Proxy (f a))) invalid
```

Just, as I said, such an instance shouldn't be defined. I think what you actually want is something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol, KnownSymbol, symbolVal)

data Wrapper (n :: String) (a :: *)
   = Wrapper a
   | TypeMismatch String

instance ∀ a s . (IsString a, FromJSON a, KnownSymbol s)
                     => FromJSON (Wrapper s a) where
  parseJSON (String s) = Wrapper <$> pure (fromString $ unpack s)
  parseJSON invalid    = TypeMismatch $ symbolVal @s Proxy
```

No classes needed.

Comment: thanks @leftaroundabout, very clear and informative!